# Forms authentication issue

Tags: asp.net

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="1"
           name=".ASPXAUTH"
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="false"
           defaultUrl="HomePage.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
      </authentication>

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int recordExistCount = fc.Authenticate(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
           if (recordExistCount == 1)
           {
               Session["User"] = "Authenticated";
               Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
               fc.IsOnlineRecord(Session["Username"].ToString(),true);
               FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Session["Username"].ToString(), true);
           Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
           }
           else
           {
               lblStatus.Text = "Username or password specified are incorrect";
               lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Yellow;               
           }
        }
```

Forms authentication doesnt work properly. After one successfull login , I go to the website url and it doesnt go to Homepage and instead takes me again to the loginpage.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the code for your login mechanism - what are you doing in the code behind of LoginPage.aspx

Comment: there is nothing about formsauthentication class. Its just a credentials check at the login page and after successfull login it redirects to homepage.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you are not setting the Formsauthentication. Therefore, in the code behind of the LoginPage.aspx - on the login click event try something like this

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //get the user details and authenticate them against whatever means you need to
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(authenticatedUser.Email, false);
                Response.Redirect("~/HomePage.aspx");
            }
            catch
            {
                //catch any errors here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited the question with code behind file. What am I missing?

Comment: Nope buddy it doesnt work. I have added the code in code behind file

Comment: you also need to look at @blowdart's answer about the TimeOut

Comment: Ok now I increased the timeout to 10 minutes. But it still goes to login page. I dont really know what the deal with ASPAUTH is exactly
can we start chat?

Answer (score 2):

Increase the timeout. 1 minute is incredibly low. I believe 20 minutes is the default. Also, set slidingexpiration to true otherwise every user will have to re-authenticate at 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

How you are performing the login? Is it with the login control or are you doing it manually?

If you're doing it manually run your app through fiddler and see if the .ASPAUTH cookie is being created and dropped. Increase the timeout from a minute. Post your manual code so we can see how you're creating the token.